# Textblock Runs Binding perfomance

Tags: c#, wpf

(Sorry, google Translate)

I'm writing a WPF chat and I'm running into a Textblock.Inlines binding performance issue.

The problem occurs when switching tabs TabControl (actually it's not a TabControl, but just a list on the right with bots and in the middle of the ContentControl).
I tried using a TabControl where the tabs are not unloaded, but the problem remains.

When I switch, the interface freezes, especially if there are a lot of messages.

I tried to make Bindind isAsync true for each element, but the list is loaded from top to bottom, I would like it the other way around.

My ChatControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MinecraftBotManager.CustomControls.ChatControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MinecraftBotManager.CustomControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"             
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:assist="clr-namespace:MinecraftBotManager.Asists"
         xmlns:mat="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MinecraftBotManager.Models"
         xmlns:mcm="clr-namespace:MinecraftLibrary.MinecraftModels;assembly=MinecraftLibrary"
         xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MinecraftBotManager.ViewModel"
         xmlns:avalon="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
         xmlns:beh="clr-namespace:MinecraftBotManager.Behaviors"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid x:Name="GridChat">        
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollChat" Height="300" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="30" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ChatList" ItemsSource="{Binding ChatQueue,IsAsync=True}"                           
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ChatTextBlock/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Grid Margin="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button Visibility="Collapsed" Name="ButtonExpand" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" Width="50" Height="50">
            <Button.Content>
                <mat:PackIcon Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="3" Kind="ExpandMore"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <Grid Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="GridEllipse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Fill="#FF387CCF"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NewMessageCount" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

ChatTextBlock

```
<UserControl x:Class="MinecraftBotManager.CustomControls.ChatTextBlock"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MinecraftBotManager.CustomControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         xmlns:converts="clr-namespace:MinecraftBotManager.Converters"
          xmlns:beh="clr-namespace:MinecraftBotManager.Behaviors"
          xmlns:mat="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:attached="clr-namespace:MinecraftBotManager.Asists"
         MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border},Path=ActualWidth}"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <converts:StringToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="StringToVisi"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock attached:TextBlockExtensions.BindableInlines="{Binding ColoredText}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" x:Name="Text" Foreground="White" FontFamily="JetBrains Mono" FontSize="14">
                       
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Text,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource StringToVisi}}" Margin="15,0,0,0" Height="auto" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="1" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" >
            <Button.Content>
                <mat:PackIcon Kind="ContentCopy" Width="14" Margin="0" Height="auto"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

ChatMessageVM

```
public List<Run> ColoredText { get; set; } = new List<Run>();
```

At the moment I have technical difficulties in migrating to UWP and Net Core (Yes, I have a Net Framework 4.8 project).

And one more little question: Is it right to bind Runs? I get json and it says what the text should look like.

Solution:
I solved the problem. It turned out to be simple: I used Listbox in material design, where there is no virtualization.

Comment: This is not binding related. This is rendering related. You have to many items. Since you use the ItemsControl you don't have UI virtualization. You must remove the ScrollViewer and replace the ItemsControl with a ListBox. ListBox already comes with a ScrollViewer and has UI virtualization by default.

Comment: I'm going to try now...

Comment: Wow. It worked. Strange, I've tried this before, apparently I used Material Design ListBox

Comment: Glad you solved it. Would mind putting your solution into its own answer? That follows the expected format of this site.